# invalid Syntax Error in python print statement using File

Tags: python

```
print('Group output sizes: |A| = {}, |B| = {}'.format(len(A),len(B)),    file=stderr)
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please help what this error is about? I initially thought its because of print syntax but it is not I think.

Please help.

Comment: Don't run Python 3 code in Python 2.

Comment: `print` does not accept keyword arguments in Python 2.x

Answer (score 5):

It seems as if you are trying to use Python 3.x's [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function in Python 2.x.  In order to do so, you need to first import `print_function` from [`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

Place the following line at the very top of your source file, after any comments and/or docstrings:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

---

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> # Python 2.x interpreter session
...
>>> print('a', 'b', sep=',')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('a', 'b', sep=',')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

```
>>> # Another Python 2.x interpreter session
...
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('a', 'b', sep=',')
a,b
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the Python 3 `print` syntax in Python 2.

Either use a Python 3 interpreter, or rewrite the `print` like so:

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'Group output sizes: |A| = {}, |B| = {}'.format(len(A),len(B))
```